# Can write in a file in "Development mode" but can't write "Distrubiton mode" in electron

Tags: electron, fs, electron-packager

I have a problem with electron. I'm trying to write data(adding a new category for example) in a JSON file with using fs. It works great in development mode without any error. However, I build my application with using electron-packager and run it. When I was trying to push a data nothing happend. It did not give even an error. I refreshed/closed and reopened it and categories were still same, nothing changed.

Here is my a part of main.js code.

```
 ipcMain.on("newCategory", (err, data) =>{ // data is coming from front end with ipcRenderer.send
        let href = data.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase();
        let myData =[ {
            name : data,
            href : href
        }]; 

        const catFile = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"category.json"),'utf8'); // firstly read current file.
        const json = JSON.parse(catFile);
        json.push(...myData); // push it as a json object

            try{
                fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"category.json"),JSON.stringify(json,null,2));  // write new version of file.
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }

});
```

Also it's my electron-packager code

```
electron-packager . myApp --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/myIcon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="myApp"
```

What is wrong with this code? Why it does not work in distribution mode? How can i make it work as development mode. Thanks for helping.

Comment: might it is permission issue, which OS you are using ?

Comment: `__dirname` I think in the packaged app is in a readonly asar file. Try changing the writing path to something outside of asar archives.

Comment: My OS is Windows

Comment: I fixed it !! I guess @hijleh was right. I used electron-store package to write my data. Thx for your help. :)